# Backup Credentials from Credentials Manager manually

Tags: credentials-manager

Is there a way to backup the Credentials without using the standard "Backup Credentials"? Like a Folder, where all Credentials are saved?

I have to write the credentials to a share, everytime the user logs out (xenapp virtual desktop).

I found this location: "C:\Users\%username\%AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials" but this folder is empty (I enabled show hidden files)

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. I had to uncheck "Hide protected OS files" in the folder options